# Was ist die genaue Bedeutung von "zynisch"?

Tags: meaning

I am trying to understand the second meaning given for ["zynisch" in Duden online](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/zynisch#Bedeutunga):

> (2) eine gefühllose, mitleidlose, menschenverachtende Haltung zum Ausdruck bringend, die besonders in bestimmten Angelegenheiten, Situationen als konträr, paradox und als jemandes Gefühle verachtend und verletzend empfunden wird

I think I get the gist of it, but I'm still unsure of some particulars and shades of the overall meaning. I give here my best translation to better point out the points I'm usure of:

> Expressing an insensitive, uncompassionate, disdainful (?) attitude/behaviour, which, especially in specific matters or situations, is felt as antagonistic (?), paradoxical (?), and as disdaining and hurting someone’s feelings.

I'll get the particulars out of the way first. It doesn't matter if there isn't a good one-word translation; I just want ot undestand the meaning.

I found **menschenverachtend** in google translator only, and it says it means **inhuman**, but, not trusting google translator 100%, I'd rather listen to native expertise.

My **antagonistic** for **konträr** is pure guesswork: it's the only thing I can see related to **contrary** that makes sense to me in this context. Could you explain?

What does **paradox** mean there? "Perplexing," "hard/impossible to understand"? Does it mean people get shocked because they don't understand why the **Zyniker** is so mean?

Now regarding the overall meaning. Why is **in bestimmten Angelegenheiten, Situationen** important? Does it simply mean a **Zyniker** does not have to be **zynisch** all the time? Or is there a finer point to it? And lastly it would be great if someone could clarify the overal menaing with examples of the word in context.

Feel free to answer in German

Thanks a lot in advance. And if you're wondering I got into this whlile looking at the differences between the meanings of "cynical", Portuguese "cínico", French "cynique", and "zynisch" (they´re all rather different, though Duden meaning (1) is similar to French), and the Duden definition proved rather trying.

Answer (score 3):

If you combine your translation of *menschenverachtend* with Google's, you get the correct sense: disdainful of human values and the value of human life. The word is mostly used to describe opinions, in which case there is no implication that these are actually realised as acts. But if they are, the acts can be described as inhuman. A lot of things that intoxicated people write in political internet forums are best described as *menschenverachtend*.

Google Translator is really poor as a substitute for a dictionary. For translations between German and major other languages, use [dict.leo.org](http://dict.leo.org). It would not have helped with *menschenverachtend*, but it gets *konträr* right: *contrarian*. (In this particular case your translation *antagonistic* is better.)

(Actually - I guess translating *menschenverachtend* to Spanish or Italian with dict.leo.org would also have helped you, after all. The result is *misantropico*, which clarifies yet another facet of the word in addition to the French translation *dédaigneux*, which I guess you already found.)

*Paradox* just translates to *paradoxical*, which Wiktionary explains as "having self-contradictory properties". That's what it means - in general and in this context.

Comment: I've just tried dict.leo.org.Thanks for the tip. Don't think _misantrópico_ is the right spanish equivalent though. The [Dicionário da Real Academia Espanola says misántropo](http://lema.rae.es/drae/?val=mis%C3%A1ntropo) (you only get a proper definition for the noun) is a person who, owing to a sad disposition, shuns human contact. I wonder what's self-contradictory in a "zynische" attitude?!

Comment: Even though the original sense of *paradox* (against generally accepted teachings/beliefs) might be a better fit here, I still think it isn't intended since this meaning doesn't really exist in German any more. *Paradox* in this case is not an objective description but is reported as how people feel about cynics. In sense, disdaining all humans is paradoxical because it means you have to disdain yourself, which then undermines your basis for disdaining anything at all.